# Audit information on a relation table with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, sql-server-2008, audit

I am using NHibernate on a project. The database is required to have creation date and creator user fields on relation tables but I do not want to map the relations to domains. My db design is like:

```
school (id, name, credate, creuser)
student (id, name, credate, creuser)
school_student(id, school_id, student_id, credate, creuser)
```

For school_student.id, I use autoincrement, pk, not null, so I do not have to map it.
NHibernate automatically manages relations so I do not have to map school_id and student_id.
For credate, I can use getdate() function, so I do not have to map this field.

But for creuser field, I cannot think of a way that so I do not have to create a domain class for school_student table. How can I escape creating a domain for school_student table? Is there a way of sending creuser information to database each time NHibernate inserts a recort into this table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`SUSER_SNAME()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174427.aspx) as the default for the column if it's a direct connection.

Indirectly (eg via a web site) you'll have to send the value of [`Context.User.Identity`](http://www.secnewsgroups.net/dotnet/t155-windowsidentity-vs-user-identity.aspx) because the DB engine does not know who the end user is. You'll have to map it in nHibernate.

Comment: But this is a web app and every user uses the same connection string.